# When a phone sends a series of zeros over radio waves to a cell tower, how does the tower know how many in a row it is?

Tags: wireless

So if a 1 is represented by 100 MHz and 0 is 50 MHz, 101 would be 100 50 100. But if the phone sent let’s say 5 zeros in a row, how can the cell tower know if it was one zero or 3 or 5 or 7 since they’re all the same frequency?

Comment: You are confused because it is symbols that are sent, not data zeros and ones. Symbols are designed to prevent a long string of zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the responsibility of the physical layer is to encode the data into symbols that are sent "over the wire." For example, some variants of ethernet use [4B5B encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4B5B) that sends five bits on the wire for every four bits of data. This is to prevent more than three zeroes in a row that could throw off the clocking.

There are many different encoding schemes, and you will find that physical-layer protocols without external clocking have an encoding scheme that will facilitate maintaining the clock to prevent too many of the same signal in a row that can throw off the clock.